# Interceptor method not being invoked

Tags: logging, jakarta-ee, ejb, interceptor

I have written the following test code for testing InterceptorBinding in EJB as explained [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_134_interceptors_1_1):

Bean Class:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Interceptors ({LoggingInterceptor.class})
public class TestInterceptor {

 @PostConstruct
 public int func1()
 {
     System.out.println("here1");
     return 0;
 }

 public void func2()
 {
     System.out.println("here2");
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    TestInterceptor t = new TestInterceptor();
    t.func1();
    t.func2();
 }
}
```

Interceptor Binding:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Log {
}
```

Interceptor:
    @Interceptor
    @Log
    public class LoggingInterceptor {

```
 private java.util.logging.Logger logger =
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("theLogger");

 @AroundInvoke
 public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
     logger.log(Level.INFO, "here ", context.getMethod().getName());
     return context.proceed();
 }

}
```

JSP file:

```
<%@page import="test.TestInterceptor"%>
<%@page import="javax.ejb.EJB"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>Hello World!</h1>
     <%
  TestInterceptor object = new TestInterceptor();
  %>
  <%=object.func1()%>
 </body>
</html>
```

However the intercept method is not being invoked. Can you please help me identify the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are directly instantiating TestInterceptor, which means the EJB container does not have an opportunity to apply interceptors.  This will not work, even for @LocalBean.  You need to look up or inject a reference to the EJB instead.